# VSDoc alternative?

Tags: javascript, comments, minify, vsdoc

VSDoc is an awesome way of commenting Javascript, and I particularly like the ability to make one Javascript file 'depend' on another. This paves the way for Javascript minifiers/combiners that take into account proper ordering of script includes.

The only thing that might bother some is that it's **VS**-Doc.

Are there any competing formats that are vendor-neutral?

And how widely is the VSDoc standard used by non-Microsoft IDEs such as Eclipse, etc?

Comment: *"...the VSDoc standard..."* The VSDoc *format*, surely? Or has it been submitted to and accepted by a standards body? (It's not part of the C# standard, although it's an *informational* annex in the document.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard that is used the most is JsDoc, as implemented by [jsdoc-toolkit](http://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/). The syntax is short and concise, and is easy to parse.

There are many tools that can generate documentation from these, such as [ext-doc](http://code.google.com/p/ext-doc/), and most IDE's have built in support for this.

This does not have any statements for annotating dependencies, but this is really more a minifier issue than a documentation issue as any comment can include the list of dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. BTW - noticed it's been renamed to jsdoc-toolkit. http://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/